# Developing with NodeJS code and SlackAPI to create PFBot

Tags: javascript, node.js, slack-api

Recently I had a idea for a Slack Bot that would filter what a user says. I.E User says (a bad word). PFBot would see that message and change the word to "@#%$&" depending on how long the word is.

Now I am fairly new to this but I knew what needed to happen.

1. The bot would need to read the message.
2. The bot would compare that message to a list of bad words.
3. If the bot finds one then the message is filtered. (Turning the word into "@#%$".
4. The new message with filtered words would be reposted as that user.

I started work on it but since I am new with the Slack API and NodeJS I hit a rode block and I have no clue on how to get it working.

**My first specific problem is:** I can't find a way for the Bot to read a new message posted in chat.

Here is my code: https://github.com/wiredbrother/Slack-PFBot
 You will be interested in the Skills/hears.js file. That is where the magic happens. Or just look here >

```
var fs = require('fs');
var path = require('path');
var readStream = fs.createReadStream(path.join(__dirname, 
'../profanity-filter') + '/swears.txt', 'utf8');
var data = '';
readStream.on('data', function(chunk) {
data += chunk;
}).on('end', function() {
console.log(data);
});

module.exports = function(controller) {

controller.hears(['^hello$'], 'direct_message,direct_mention', function(bot, message) {
    bot.reply(message, "Hi there, you're on workspace: " + message.team)
});

controller.hears([data], 'direct_message,direct_mention', function(bot, message) {
    var filter = require('../profanity-filter/lib/filter.js');
    filter.setReplacementMethod('grawlix');
    filter.setGrawlixChars(['!', '@', '#', '$', '%', '&']);
    var thing = filter.clean(data);
    bot.reply(message, "The bad word is now: " + thing)
});

};
```

I also found a utility online for NodeJS that filters words. That is in the Profanity-Filter folder. 
You would be interested in Profanity-Filter/lib/filter.js.

I would love some guidance on this as a new coder.

Thank you for any advice you can give!

~ wiredbrother

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Getting new messages**

To get new messages you need to enable [events](https://api.slack.com/events-api) for your bot. Once enables your bots will automatically receive every new message, which is send to a channel that your bot user is a member of.

I have never used botkit myself, but apparently you can check the documentation [here](https://github.com/howdyai/botkit/blob/master/docs/slack-events-api.md) (#6) for how to enable events for the botkit.

**Removing profanity**

To me knowledge is not possible, to change the message from another user. There is [chat.udpate](https://api.slack.com/methods/chat.update), which updates a messages. But that only works for your own messages.

Instead you could delete messages form other users with [chat.delete](https://api.slack.com/methods/chat.delete), that contains profanity (and inform the user with a direct message about his transgression).

Comment: Thank you so much for your response. As for the profanity part my thought was not to update there message but to delete it and then repost that message with the filtered content as the user. That would use this part of the slack API https://api.slack.com/methods/chat.postMessage and post as a user. Although I have no idea on how to incorporate that into my code... 
Thank you for your help so far!

Comment: np. Unfortunately its not really possible to repost a message as another user with the Slack API. You can "fake" the username and icon, but it will still have the "app" tag next to the message, indicating it came from a bot.

Comment: Well could I make it to where it deletes the message and sends a ethereal message saying that there was a bad word in it and they can not post that message?

Comment: sure that should work. I made a similar bot that blocks every not authorized user from posting messages in a channel by deleting that message and then sending a direct message to him.